# While implementing Google Maps using the Javascript API, the whole map doesn't seem to be loading for me

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I get big areas of gray that never fill in - even if I zoom. You can view a sample here - http://birdbrain.vernerwebstudio.com/professional-development/. This was working fine before, but all of a sudden one day, it just started doing this. I've removed any custom functionality that was added thinking that was the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set some styling in the `style-custom.css` file which affects the map's images (`<img>` elements):

```
#pln-map .gm-style-iw img, #pln-map .gm-style img {
    height: 145px;
    width: 145px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Most important is: **border-radius: 50%;**

Comment: That was definitely the issue.  The offending css selector was this:
#pln-map .gm-style img

Thank you!